# libaums: Could not find libaums.aar

Tags: android, build.gradle

Does anybody know [libaums](https://github.com/magnusja/libaums)? 
I'm tried to integrate it into my project, but if I include

```
compile 'com.github.magnusja:libaums:libaums-v0.5.5@aar'
```

in my gradle dependencies, I get the message
"Could not find libaums.aar".
When I leave the @aar out:

```
compile 'com.github.magnusja:libaums:libaums-v0.5.5'
```

I get the message
"Module depends on one or more Android Libraries but is a jar".

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
compile 'com.github.mjdev:libaums:0.5.5'
```

the answer to this question is compile 'com.github.mjdev:libaums:0.5.5'